# Custom java calculator troubleshooting

Tags: java, swing

New programmer here, I have been working for a few days on this bit of code that is meant to create a UI where I input a basement's perimeter length (textfield integer), if a new pump is needed (combobox string), if there is an outlet nearby (combobox string), and how many hours It will take to prepare a site (textfield integer), and I calculate my costs to complete a job. I was able to set up a UI where I can enter the inputs and press a button to calculate but I'm having trouble connecting the button I made to the formula I made to generate a price. Here is my code:

```
package packagepackage;

import packagepackage.HintTextFieldUI; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CP_GUI implements ActionListener {
    String[] sumpo = {"New sump pump","Existing sump pump"};
    String[] electo = {"There is an outlet within 6 feet of sump pump","There is no outlet nearby, or I do not need a new one"};
    Integer estimatex = 0;
    String esto = String.valueOf(estimatex);
    public volatile String estimatoof = "Estimated Cost: ${}".format(esto);
    private JComboBox sump = new JComboBox(sumpo);
    private JComboBox elec = new JComboBox(electo);
    private JTextField linear = new JTextField();
    private JTextField prep = new JTextField();
    private JLabel title = new JLabel("Drain Tile Calculator");
    private JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate!");
    public JLabel estimate = new JLabel(estimatoof);
    
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   
   
     public CP_GUI() {   
        linear.addActionListener(this);
        calculate.addActionListener(this);
        elec.addActionListener(this);
        sump.addActionListener(this);
        prep.addActionListener(this);

        // the panel with the button and text
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(400, 400, 100, 100));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(linear);
        panel.add(sump);
        panel.add(elec);
        panel.add(prep);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(title);
        calculate.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(calculate);
        
        

        // set up the frame and display it
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Drain Tile Calculator");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        linear.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Perimeter length", true));
        prep.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Hours of preptime", true));}
    
       


    // create one Frame
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CP_GUI();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource()==linear) {String input = linear.getText();
        Integer pars = Integer.parseInt(input);
        Integer distVar = pars *= 13;
        estimatex += distVar;
        } else if (e.getSource()==sump) {String inputa = sump.getToolTipText();
        int sumpa = 0;
        if(inputa == "New sump pump" | inputa == "yes") {
            sumpa += 260;}
        estimatex += sumpa;
        } else if (e.getSource()==elec) {String inputb =elec.getToolTipText();
                int eleca = 0;
                if("There is an outlet within 6 feet of the sump pump".equals(inputb)) {
                    eleca += 1;
                }
            eleca *= 280;   
            estimatex += eleca;
            }
            else if (e.getSource()==prep) {String inputc = prep.getText();
            int parsa = Integer.parseInt(inputc);
             int prepCost = parsa += 1;
            prepCost *= 110;
            estimatex += prepCost;
            } else if (e.getSource()==linear) {
                String disto = linear.getText();
                int di = Integer.parseInt(disto);
                di *= 13;
                String pumpo = (String)sump.getSelectedItem();
                int sumpo = 0;
                if ("New sump pump".equals(pumpo)) {
                    sumpo += 260;
                }
                String ele = (String)elec.getSelectedItem();
                int elc = Integer.parseInt(ele);
                elc *= 280;
                String clea = prep.getText();
                int cla = Integer.parseInt(clea);
                cla += 1;
                cla *= 110;
                int cali = 0;
                cali += di;
                cali += sumpo;
                cali += elc;
                cali += cla;
                estimatex = cali;
            }
        
         
    }
}
```

Edit: Made the suggested edits made so far and now the UI opens and works, the only issue is that the estimated price does not show up. Am I connecting the action listener correctly?

Comment: Don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: *"I'm having trouble"* Be specific. What trouble? And while I'm here, what is your question? Telling us your troubles (or mentioning you're having trouble) is *not* a question.

Comment: *"The exception it is throwing is EventQueue-0..."* Ah, I discovered that hidden down after the end of the code. But it's still not enough information. Copy/Paste the entire stack trace related to that exact code seen above.

Answer (score 1):

Your "primary" problem is right here...

```
String disto = String.valueOf(linear);
```

where `linear` is a `JTextField`, so the above call will generate something like...

```
javax.swing.JTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.apple.laf.AquaTextFieldBorder@4e323305,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=128,g=128,b=128],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=0,g=0,b=0],selectionColor=com.apple.laf.AquaImageFactory$SystemColorProxy[r=165,g=205,b=255],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]
```

which is obviously not what you're looking for.

You should probably be just doing something like...

```
String disto = linear.getText();
```

`pumpo == "New sump pump"` is also not how you compare a `String` in Java, you should be using `"New sump pump".equals(pumpo)` ... but I suspect you're going to have the same issues as mentioned above.

I really recommend you take the time to read through [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) as well as taking the time to come to grips with the core basics of the language